# React: how to pass arguments to the callback

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I have a list of elements inside my react component, and I want them to be clickable. On click I call some external function passing item ID in arguments:

```
render () {
  return (
    <ul>
      {this.props.items.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id} onClick={() => {doSomething(item.id)}></li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

This code works, but it has a big performance drawback: a lot of new anonymous functions are being created on each call to `render`.

**How can I pass that `doSomething` function as a reference here while still being able to provide a `item.id` to it?**

Comment: @AndrewLi I cannot, because `item.id` is changing because it's inside a list

Comment: I mean either way, you're going to have use bind or arrow functions (I'd prefer the latter), which both create new functions... is it really a performance problem?

Comment: @AndrewLi consider this list containing thousands of elements. `render` itself is being called frequently, but anonymous function is called even more frequently because it's inside the `map`. I don't think it would cause any problems on small sets, but I'm seeking for solution for large datasets

Comment: I don't think this is possible. There might be an extremely hacky way but I don't think this is really supported without bind or arrow functions.

Answer (score 16):

You could use **data-attributes**, to set the correct id on each item while using the same function:

```
function doSomethingFromEvent(event){
  return doSomething(event.target.dataset.id);
}

render () {
  return (
    <ul>
      {this.props.items.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id} data-id={item.id} onClick={doSomethingFromEvent}></li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

When setting `data-*` attributes in your element, you can get it back with `dataset`, in the form of a hash. For example, in `doSomethingFromEvent` I have `event.target.dataset = {id: *id*}`. [See more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

This is even cleaner when updating a hash (the state for example), with `<li key={item.id} data-myattriute={myvalue} onClick={this.handleClick}></li>`, I can simply define `handleClick` such as:

```
handleClick(event){
    // Here event.target.dataset = {myattribute: myvalue}

    Object.assign(myObject, event.target.dataset);
    // or
    this.setState(event.target.dataset);
}
```

Coming back to your problem, the great thing with this approach is that if you ensure your container element (ul) cannot be clicked outside its children with data-attributes (li), which is your case, you can declare the function on it:

```
render () {
  return (
    <ul onClick={doSomethingFromEvent}>
      {this.props.items.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id} data-id={item.id}></li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Now your function is created a single time, and is not even repeated in each item.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a partially applied or higher order function to enclose the `item.id` and pass it along. So let's look at a toy example of this:

```
class App {

   partiallyApplied = id => e => {
     console.log(id,'this is passed in first')
     console.log(e,'this is passed in second')
   }

   render(){
     return (
       <button onClick={this.partiallyApplied(1234)}>Click Me</button>
     )
   }

}
```

Now you have access to `1234` along with your `event` object

This is use `transform-class-properties` babel plugin. If do not or cannot use that, you can probably do something like this:

```
partiallyApplied(id){
  return function(e){
   console.log(id,'this is id')
   console.log(e,'this is event')
  }
}
```

but then you will have to bind `this` during your call and I just don't like that everywhere.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how it affects performance. Because looks like it's anyway will create new function per item, same as with bind or arrow functions.

Comment: It does return a new function each time. I am not sure there is a way around that though since we are wanting to use a new closure for each `id`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new component for every item in the array and use the props, [**like this**](http://jsbin.com/nofuyuriwa/1/edit?js,console,output):

```
class Li extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <li onClick={this.onClick}> {this.props.children} </li>;
  }
  onClick = () => {
    console.log(this.props.item);
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      {id: 1, name: 'one'},
      {id: 2, name: 'two'},
      {id: 3, name: 'three'},
    ]
  };
  render() {
    return <ul> 
      {this.state.items.map(i => 
        <Li key={i.id} item={i}>{i.name}</Li>
      )} 
    </ul>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it will perform even worse then creating new function per item with bind or arrow function?

Comment: I personally don't like this solution because now the underlying component is aware of the function it needs to call and all the arguments it has to provide. It breaks single responsibility principle here

Comment: @Girafa That's true. But if you have a use case where creating a new context for each item on each render is too expensive, it might be worth breaking that principle with 8 lines of code.

Comment: @dfsq While it is true that the initial rendering might be just as expensive as arrow functions, the difference is that if `<Li>` is a PureComponent, then it wouldn't rerender each iteration since its props don't change. In case of an arrow function, however, the props DO change - A new function is created everytime and a render would have to occur.